# create trigger not working in mysql

Tags: mysql

i am trying to write a trigger which validates insert statements before inserting in the table

table structure:

[image]

This is the code that i wrote

```
DELIMITER
    $$
CREATE TRIGGER check_date_format
INSERT BEFORE ON
job_histry FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN 
SET @bool=NEW.end_date LIKE '--/--/----';
IF @bool THEN
    INSERT
INTO
    job_histry
VALUES(
    NULL,
    NEW.start_date,
    NEW.end_date,
    NEW.job_id,
    NEW.department_id
) ;
    END IF ;
END
$$
```

This is the error that i received:

> **#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'INSERT BEFORE ON job_histry FOR EACH ROW BEGIN SET @bool=NEW.end_date LIKE '' at line 2**

why is this happening?

I am using localhost xampp server.

Comment: Why have you tagged this mysql - when MariaDB  is in the error message

Comment: i have no idea, i am using mysql on local host xamp server

Comment: Is your table really called `job_histry`?

Comment: yes.. @NicoHaase

Answer (score 1):

You have the trigger type (INSERT) and time (BEFORE) in the wrong order.

It should read

```
BEFORE INSERT ON job_histry
```